# jquery slider error... if I use Jquery cookies

Tags: jquery, slider, uislider

I am trying to use a Jquery slider something like this (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) and I was able to set up right. But on page load i am getting a "jquery cookie is not a function" error. The problem is the file jquery-1.3.2.min dot js is conflicting with jquery.cookie dot js file.  Please suggest me your expert advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a slider-specific problem. Are there other functions on your page that might cause this error? Do you have an example URL we can see, or can you post the code that is giving you the problem?

Comment: Sorry.. My bad.. It is conflicting with some other Jquery files. Thank you for your reply Honeybuzzer.